# Why PHP Ratchet Websocket connection with Nginx is not working?

Tags: nginx, websocket, ratchet

I'm running websocket using PHP Ratchet. Here is code :

```
$allowed_origins = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '95.179.194.135'];
$host = '95.179.194.135'; 
$app = new Ratchet\App($host, 8080, '0.0.0.0');
$app->route('/', new Cmc, $allowed_origins);
$app->run();
```

Web server is Nginx . Here is nginx configuration:

```
upstream websocket {
server  95.179.194.135:8080;
} 
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key;
index index.php index.html;
root /var/www/html;
server_name 95.179.194.135;
location /cmchat {
    proxy_pass    http://websocket;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}
}
```

Ratchet service is running fine as I checked in terminal.
[image: ratchet service status]

Here is javascript code to connect to websocket:

```
const wsChat = new WebSocket("ws://95.179.194.135/cmchat");
```

but its never connected.

telnet connection working :
telnet 95.179.194.135 8080   this command showing this:

```
Trying 95.179.194.135...
Connected to 95.179.194.135.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

but when from javascript its never connected.

can anyone help me to find find issue why its not working.

thanks

Comment: I have a similar issue. How can I get in touch with you? Please share your email, telegram id or anything to connect. I expect you must have solved it till now. Please, it's very urgent. Help me out.